# Update geometry in ArcGIS Relationship class between point and lines

Tags: arcgis-desktop, editing, relationship-class, utility-network

I have set up two relationship classes with a pipe (storm_pipe) and its structures (storm_struc). Each pipe has a from_struc_id and a to_struc_id, both of which point to a id in the storm_struc layer.

I'm wondering how to set up ArcMap editing so that if I move a storm_pipe endpoint, the related endpoint moves with it. Also the same in reverse, if I move a storm_struc, the related pipe endpoint would also move.

A couple of notes, I don't have access to the network analyst extension so I don't believe I can utilize geometric networks. I only have access to a Standard ArcGIS Desktop license.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [Geometric Network](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/geometric-networks/about-creating-geometric-networks.htm) will do what you want.

Geometric Networks [**do not** require the Network Analyst extension](http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000010092)

> Question:
> Is the Network Analyst extension required to build a geometric
> network?
>
> Answer:
> No, the Network Analyst extension is not required to build and edit a
> geometric network.

Geometric Networks are available to create/edit with both Standard and Advanced licenses, and viewable using a Basic License.

> License:
>
> Although geometric networks can be both created and edited in ArcGIS
> for Desktop Advanced and Standard, they are read-only in Basic

(from [Managing a geometric network](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/geometric-networks/managing-a-geometric-network.htm))

Additional to moving a point when moving a connect pipe, it will also move the end of the next connected pipes as well, keeping all connectivity.  These moves are pivoted at vertices.